# C Program, file output to txt from loop

Tags: c, loops, cmd, io

i am taking an introduction class to C programming right now and we were assign to make some kind one item cash register program that calculate taxes and rounds it up to 5 cents (since here in quebec 1 cents dont exist no more) and i used a different method than the teacher to round up my numbers to 5 cents.

He asked me to proove that method. so i decided to write a little program, why not huh ?! Wrote the code, program works perfectly but here is the catch, the number of output is too big to display them all on the cmd window. so I need either to increase the ammount of data that the cmd window can display (i need it to about 10 000) or make it output and append the data to a txt file. in Python no problem....in C not so much. Can you guys help me out ?

here is the code :

```
 int main()
  {
      float prixitem = 0.00;
      float arrondis;
      int count = 0;

       do{

       prixitem = (prixitem + 0.01);
       arrondis = (round(prixitem * 20.0)/20.0); // Round up happens here
       printf("prix : %.2f ---> %.2f\n", prixitem, arrondis );
       count = count + 1;
           } while (prixitem < 100.00);

   printf("Nombre de possibilites arrondis a 5 : %d\n", count);
   system("pause");
   return 0;
  }
```

Comment: If you're on a sane OS, you can just redirect the output to a file. `program > file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something most easily done from the command prompt:

```
c:\> myprogram > output.txt
```

EDIT:

If you want to write to a file from within the C program, you'd do this:

```
FILE *f = fopen("output.txt","w");
if (f == NULL) {
    perror("fopen failed");
    exit(1);
}
....
fprintf(f,"prix : %.2f ---> %.2f\n", prixitem, arrondis );
...
fclose(f);
```

Comment: i didnt think of that, Thanks !

Comment: @Ronin825  Glad I could help.  Fee free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: That helped me reach my goal, but for the sake of education and curiosity, How woudl i go about programming this in C ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use file pointers and fprintf to direct the output from the command line to that file. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() { 
    FILE *fp; 

    fp = fopen("/tmp/test.txt", "w+");
    fprintf(fp, "Your number = %d\n", count);

    fclose(fp);
    }
```

You can read more about this here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_file_io.htm